# New Column with query result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, apply

I need add new column with query result.

I have this Query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Arrival                              
           , Flight                                         
           , TotalPax.SumPassengers            
           , TotalPaxLocal.SumLocalPassengers  
           , STD                                         
           , STA                                         
           --, PassengerID                       
           --, Departure                     
           --, JourneyNumber
           --, SegmentNumber
           --, LegNumber           
           --, InventoryLegKey  
           --, RecordLocator
        FROM #TempLocalOrg tmp

    CROSS APPLY
    (
       SELECT COUNT(1) AS SumPassengers
            FROM #TempLocalOrg crossTemp
       WHERE tmp.Flight = crossTemp.Flight

    ) TotalPax 

    CROSS APPLY
    (
       SELECT COUNT(1) AS SumLocalPassengers
            FROM #TempLocalOrg crossTemp
       WHERE tmp.Flight        = crossTemp.Flight           
         AND tmp.Arrival       = crossTemp.Arrival
         AND tmp.SegmentNumber = 1
         AND tmp.LegNumber     = 1
    ) TotalPaxLocal
```

TotalPax is working, but, TotalPaxLocal not working, i need a Cross Apply or something like the query below:

```
    SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM #TempLocalOrg
     WHERE Flight        = 1500 
       AND Arrival       = 'FLN'
       AND SegmentNumber = 1
       AND LegNumber     = 1
```

So, i need replace the Cross Apply TotalPaxLocal for this query.

Wrong OutPut:

```
Arrival | Flight | TotalPax | TotalPaxLocal | ETD              | ETA
--------|--------|----------|---------------|------------------|----------------    
FLN     | 1500   | 144      | 144           | 05/22/2015 08:25 | 05/22/2015 09:35
```

Correct OutPut:

```
Arrival | Flight | TotalPax | TotalPaxLocal | ETD              | ETA
--------|--------|----------|---------------|------------------|----------------    
FLN     | 1500   | 144      | 52            | 05/22/2015 08:25 | 05/22/2015 09:35
```

Comment: what does `not working` mean

Comment: TotalPaxLocal not working, i need replace the cross apply TotalPaxLocal for this query:                                                                           SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM #TempLocalOrg
   WHERE Flight        = 1500 
     AND Arrival       = 'FLN'
     AND SegmentNumber = 1
     AND LegNumber     = 1

Comment: Can you give example output?  We don't know what 'not working' means.

Comment: Wrong output:

Arrival ; Flight ; TotalPax ; TotalPaxLocal ; ETD ; ETA
FLN     ; 1500   ; 144      ; 144           ; 22/05/2015 08:25    ; 22/05/2015 09:35

Correct output:
Arrival ; Flight ; TotalPax ; TotalPaxLocal ; ETD ; ETA
FLN     ; 1500   ; 144      ; 52            ; 22/05/2015 08:25 ; 22/05/2015 09:35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use window functions for these calculations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tmp.Arrival, tmp.Flight,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Flight) as NumPassengers, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN SegmentNumber = 1 AND LegNumber = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY Flight, Arrival)
          ) as NumLocalPassengers,
       STD, STA   
FROM #TempLocalOrg tmp;
```